# Is it safe to install a wire nut inside a base board heater?

Tags: electrical, safety, wire, heater, temperature

My baseboard heater has its junction box built into it, meaning there are wire nuts in a section of the heater.  However the ground has been broken off more interior / near the heating element.  I need to cause it to reach the junction box so I can ground it.  Is it safe to use a wire nut more inside the heater / nearer to the heating element?  I think wire nuts are rated to 105C and a baseboard heater shouldn't be getting nearly that hot.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a crimp ferrule the reason being the wire nut could melt and then create more problems the crimp is just a metal ring that connects the wires together nothing to melt. Years ago we had to use crimps in all the boxes for the grounds at least in the areas I worked.